# Sqldeveloper adds spaces between schema and object

Tags: formatting, oracle-sqldeveloper

The latest version of Sqldeveloper (18.3) seems to break autoformatting.

sample query

```
select * from hr.whatever;
```

in 18.2, the query would format to

```
select *
  from hr.whatever;
```

now, sqldeveloper 18.3 (using the same settings) is formatting this to

```
select *
  from hr . whatever ;
```

the spaces between schema and object are annoying - and I found no way of switching this off.

I tried to copy the default "custom formatting" from 18.2 to 18.3, however this does not help.

My formatting options:

[image]

Hope someone is able to point me to the proper formatting option to disable this.

Comment: It's a bug in 18.3 - reset your formatter preferences and you'll be back to 'normal.' this has been fixed for 18.4

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.

Happens when you upgrade to 18.3 AND if you -

> If a customer has ever visited the Custom Format Page, and hit OK (not
>   Cancel) when leaving it (even though he never touch the Arbori code),
>   then the new Arbori program would be saved (with all the
>   consequences).

Consequences being what you see.

To get the formatter working as expected again, hit this button.

[image]

This bug has been fixed for version 18.4, due later this year.